# What does mean by "Two components of the same class will generate similar trees" in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I have read it in [Reactjs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reconciliation.html#motivation) documentation that "Two components of the same class will generate similar trees and two components of different classes will generate different trees." but did not understood what does it mean.

Comment: What exactly do you not understand? Are you on the same page with what kind of "tree" they're talking about?

Comment: I am talking about "Two components of the same class", here what they mean by class

Comment: I would strongly assume a *React class*, a React thing that generates a DOM *tree*.

Answer (score 1):

*Components* in this context refers to a [React Component](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html), which is JavaScript/JSX object that has a `render` function that returns a DOM node. DOM Nodes are trees, in that they can contain children DOM Nodes. These are the *Trees* being referenced.

Components are defined as classes, either using ES6 `class` syntax, or using `React.createClass`. So what that is saying is that two Component instances of the same type will produce similar DOM Node trees (the two Components will have similar structure, because they contain the same rendering logic). This is not guaranteed though, as the `render` function could contain logic that produces completely different results.

Two component instances of different types may have very different DOM node trees, since they probably don't use the same `render` function.

Comment: That is likely, but it can just as well generate very different trees depending on the logic defined in `render()`